# Laravel. How to get a record, that has all user ids in related table?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

There is a chat table and intermediate table.

I need to get from the chat table only those chats for which all user identifiers are found.
[image]

[image]

Now I am getting records if at least one match is found

My query

```
$chat = $this->select('chats.*')->distinct()
                     ->rightJoin("chat_user", function ($query) {
                         $query->on("chats.id", "=", "chat_user.chat_id")
                               ->whereIn("chat_user.user_id", [2, 17]);
                     })
                     ->where('chats.type', '=', 'single')
                     ->get();
```

Result

[image]

But I need a chat width id 4, because only it matches my request

I also tried to do it like this

```
$chat = $this->select('chats.*')->distinct()
                     ->rightJoin("chat_user", function ($query) use ($members_ids) {
                         $query->on("chats.id", "=", "chat_user.chat_id")
                             ->where("chat_user.user_id", 2)
                             ->where("chat_user.user_id", 17);
                     })
                     ->where('chats.type', '=', 'single')->get();
```

But result is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain SQL, this could be achieved with the following query:

```
SELECT chats.*
FROM chats
WHERE chats.type = 'single'
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM chat_user WHERE user_id = 2 AND chat_id = chats.id)
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM chat_user WHERE user_id = 7 AND chat_id = chats.id)
```

Translated into a Laravel query, we get the following:

```
$userIds = [2, 7];

$chats = DB::table('chats')
    ->where('chats.type', 'single')
    ->where(function (Builder $query) use ($userIds) {
        foreach ($userIds as $userId) {
            $query->whereExists(fn (Builder $query) => $query
                ->select(DB::raw(1))
                ->from('chat_user')
                ->where('chat_user.user_id', $userId)
                ->whereColumn('chat_user.chat_id', 'chats.id'));
        }
    })
    ->select('chats.*')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this instead:

```php
$chat = $this->select('chats.*')->distinct()
             ->rightJoin('chat_user', function ($query) {
                 $query->on('chats.id', '=', 'chat_user.chat_id')
                       ->where('chat_user.user_id', 2)
                       ->where('chat_user.user_id', 17);
             })
             ->where('chats.type', '=', 'single')
             ->get();
```

Specifying multiple where works as an `AND` condition. If you use `whereIn()` will work as an `OR` conditions for the supplied values.